# Control each style property for each background image of one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `DIV` that I want to give him 2 or more background images.
I set a style to the `DIV` class with the two images:

```
.manyImages {
    background: url(/a1.png), url(/a2.png) no-repeat;
}

 <div class="manyImages"> </div>
```

My problem is to set different background size to each image url.
 How can I control each image of many  backgroud images on one DIV for setting size,borders,color...?

**EDIT**: I want to control each image size inside the DIV, for example first image background should be **20px X 20px** the second image **40px X 45px** and so on...

Comment: it's background-size:20px 20px, 45px 40px; i already answered and also added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorthand Background: color image positionY positionY repeat;

```
background:
url(/a1.png) center center no-repeat,
url(/a2.png) left top no-repeat;
//then 

background-size:cover,auto;
//cover,contain,%,px...
```

you can't add borders to background images.

it's also hard to keep the aspect ratio if you don't use `cover` or `contain`

only in chrome you can also add the shorthand background-size right after the repeat tag by adding a `/` .. so

```
background:color url posx posy repeat / sizex sizey
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/At7g4/1/

**EDIT**

> how to set custom background sizes:

```
background:url(a.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat,url(b.jpg) 20px 0px no-repeat,url(c.jpg) 70px 0px no-repeat;
background-size:20px 20px,45px 40px,50px 50px;
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/At7g4/2/

Comment: Ohoo so you simply set the size to the all group `background-size:1px 1px,2px 2px,3px 3px;` nice. If I do it like this code I need to set each one of them. Can I just set the third image without setting and changing sizes of first and second images (dont want to touch the correct images)

Comment: adding more than 2 background images is a bad solution. in that case i would use the @tomahim's solution which someone has downvoted. if you want more control.

Comment: Well that exactly what I was looking for, didn't know it is possible to set multiple size of background

Answer (score 2):

Not a problem, and you don't need Javascript for that!

```
.manyImages {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url(/a1.png), url(/a2.png);
    background-position: center bottom, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Just adjust the position to your needs!

--Edit--

Do note that the newer browsers support this CSS3 update to backgrounds, but older browsers do not.  I do believe the list includes: Mozilla Firefox (3.6+), Safari/Chrome (1.0/1.3+), Opera (10.5+), Internet Explorer (9.0+)

Do not quote me on the list above, as I may be slightly off on one or more, but to my knowledge, this is true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to control no the size of the DIV and images positions, but each image size inside the DIV, for example first image background should be **20px X 20px** the second image **40px X 45px** and so on...

Comment: Personally, if I was doing that method.  I would have made my images say '64px by 64px' when I created the actual image. but yes, background-size:20px 20px, 40px 45px; should do the trick.

http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/  A great source of info on the current topic.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be something like that :

```
<div class="manyImages">
   <div class="image1"> </div>
   <div class="image2"> </div>
   ...
</div>
```

And on your CSS

```
.manyImages .image1 {
    background: url(/a1.png) no-repeat;
}

.manyImages .image2 {
    background: url(/a2.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Then on each CSS class you can adjust the position of your images.
The advantage is that it's supported by all the browsers.